# Sliding to next photo

Tags: android, android-fragments

How can i implement this kind of gallery? I mean when u press the arrow it slides to next photo. 
Thx for answers.

sliding to next photo

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic Solution Approach:

-Use a ImageButton for the two arrows buttons. The ImageButton is just like any other Button, except it displays an image that will commit to an action when clicked on (basic definition)

-For having the images and having a sort of power point slide show event, take a look at: http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

-The developer.android.com link contains a step by step process on creating a power point slide show type of app. You can even download the project files and take a look at the entire code.

-Essentially, a you have a ViewPager that displays X amount of fragments. Each Fragment will contain an image that you fetch. When you click the ImageButton (refer to first point), you can shift through the fragment array.

-Probably not the most efficient approach (my apologies), but its definitely a start!